# xfreerdp multimon not working on dual screen Client

Tags: rdp

I have a strange probleme with xfrreerdp. I got a rdp-Machine and a client. both are running on ubuntu and got dual screen setup.

if I do a  (executed on the left screen):
xfreerdp /monitors:0 /multimon /v:192.168.1.x

RDP-Session start on my left local screen.

If I do a (executed on the right screen):
xfreerdp /monitors:0 /multimon /v:192.168.1.x

RDP-Session start on my right local screen.

If I do a (executed on the left screen):
xfreerdp /monitors:0,1 /multimon /v:192.168.1.x

there should be openeing an RDP-Connection with dual screen on BOTH machines, local, and remote. I my case, it always starts local on the screen, where I got opened the terminal.

Is there a possibility, to get it starten on both local screens (fullscreen)?

Thanks for your help.

Tom